# Reverse a commit value in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've wrote a procedure as follows

```
Create or replace procedure raise_salary(
v_id IN emp.empno%TYPE) AS
Begin
  update emp
  set sal = sal*1.10
  where empno=v_id;
  commit;
End;
```

I realized that i didn't create an exception to rollback the value. 
I want to go back to its original value. the value cannot be decreased as i get the following error. 
ORA-20187:  Salaries cannot be decreased

how do I go back to the original value.  I've dropped the procedure but now since i already executed it, it increased it already.  Seems like its a fixed value now.  What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping the procedure has absolutely nothing to do with reversing the effects of running it.

It sounds like there is a trigger on the table preventing you from doing the update that you want to do.  One option is to disable the trigger.  The error stack from the update should tell you its name.  You would execute `ALTER TRIGGER <triggername> DISABLE`, then run your update, then `ALTER TRIGGER  ENABLE'.

Another possible workaround could be to insert the row into a second table, update it there, then delete and re-insert it in the original table.  This could also run afoul of triggers if someone has tried to prevent inserts or deletes on the table.

This is all assuming you are in an environment where bypassing logic control implemented by someone else is appropriate.  Presumably the trigger exists for a reason.

Comment: Thank you,  you were right about the trigger.  I LOVE Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
select trigger_name from user_triggers where table_name='EMP'
```

Will show you trigger names of table you want to rollback. Then disable them like previous answer show. Dont foget to enable them back.

```
Begin
For cur in (select trigger_name from user_triggers where tbale_name='EMP') loop
 Execute immediate 'alter trigger'||cur.trigger_name||' disable';
Update emp set ....your update DML;
Execute immediate 'alter trigger'||cur.trigger_name||' enable';
end loop;
End;
```

I hope, it help you.